# Actualizar valor en base de datos tras finalizar una cuenta regresiva

Tags: javascript

tengo una duda ya que javascript no es mi especialidad. He estado haciendo algunas pruebas y quiero que al final de una cuenta regresiva que encontré en internet se modifique un valor que tengo en una base de datos.
Supongamos que la tabla de la base de datos se llama alumnos y en la tabla estado tenga valor cero, y al finalizar la cuenta regresiva, cambie a uno. Como deberia hacer?
Este es mi codigo, tranquilamente lo pueden copiar y pegar para ver su funcionalidad.

```
<div id="countdown"></div>
<script>
var end = new Date('7/27/2019 11:39 AM');

    var _second = 1000;
    var _minute = _second * 60;
    var _hour = _minute * 60;
    var _day = _hour * 24;
    var timer;

    function showRemaining() {
        var now = new Date();
        var distance = end - now;
        if (distance < 0) {

            clearInterval(timer);
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'FINALIZADO';

            return;
        }
        var days = Math.floor(distance / _day);
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = days + ' dias, ';
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += hours + ' horas, ';
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += minutes + ' minutos y ';
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML += seconds + ' segundos';
    }

    timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si ya tienes el script que hace la cuenta regresiva, únicamente tendrás que ejecutar un evento que llame al código que hace el UPDATE. Ya sea por URL (GET) o por Formulario (POST) este ultimo lo puedes hacer oculto.

```
function showRemaining() {
        var now = new Date();
        var distance = end - now;
        if (distance < 0) {

            clearInterval(timer);
            document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = 'FINALIZADO';

           //AQUÍ METER LA INSTRUCCIÓN QUE HAGA EL UPDATE EN TU BASE DE DATOS, por  
            jemplo en una ventana, o puede ser otro evento.

           ventanDB=window.open("/update.php?estado=1", "MiVentana", "");

            return;
        }
```